# Multiplication in scala, details are mentioned below

Tags: scala

Am new to scala language and am trying to write a simple function to print multiplication of 2 table. And it doesn't display any result in scala.

```
def multab(tblnum: Int) = {
  var tab = 0
  for (i <-(1 to 10)) { tab += table }
  println(tab)
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Have you tried running the code?

Comment: I know am doing wrong, but how may i need to achieve to multiply the input variable 10 times the loop and print in a new line.

Comment: You need to say what the problem is, and what you've tried to solve it. Just saying that you're doing it wrong isn't a specific question that we can answer. Show what you expect, and what you're actually getting.

Comment: I don't know what you are missing, but I'm missing here a clear mission statement, a reasonably thorough implementation attempt, the expected results, and a clear error message that describes how the actual outcome deviates from the expected outcome. I'm also missing any kind of meaningful indentation. Please read about how to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think i figured it out.
def multab(tblnum: Int) =  
{
     var tab = 0
  for (i <-(1 to 10)) 
   {
  tab = tblnum*i
  println(tab)
   }
  
}

Comment: In your code in the question, tblnum isn't used. Instead you use a table out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, first you are adding a table to tab and you have not even declared what is a table ?
You just need to use tblnum in place of table.

```
    def multab(tblnum: Int) = {
    var tab = 0
    for (i <-(1 to 10)) { tab += tblnum 
    println(tab)
  }}

    scala> multab(2)
    2
    4
    6
    8
    10
    12
    14
    16
    18
    20
```

Besides that, try to avoid mutability. Prefer immutable style over mutable style.Function way of printing multiplication.

```
scala> def mulTab(num: Int) = {
     | (1 to 10).foreach{e =>
     | println(num * e)
     | }
     | }
mulTab: (num: Int)Unit

scala> mulTab(2)
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

As you have asked in how to write same thing in class,

```
scala> class Table{
     | def multab(tblnum: Int) = {
     |     var tab = 0
     |     for (i <-(1 to 10)) { tab += tblnum 
     |     println(tab)
     |   }}
     | }
defined class Table

scala> val table = new Table
table: Table = Table@6f95cd51

scala> table.multab(3)
3
6
9
12
15
18
21
24
27
30
```

And we use singleton to make an object of class and run application from there. Singleton is like a static block in java.

```
scala> object Main extends App {
     | val table = new Table
     | table.multab(3)
     | }
defined object Main
```

If your write above singleton in any IDE, it will give you option to run the application. You can read more from [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-launch-scala-application-with-object-main-method-trait)

Comment: oops! made a mistake. Thanks updating it.

Comment: Thanks @chand Kandpal for your response.

Comment: @Kandpal I have moved further into classes and am trying below code to see how i can write a method within a class. But am not getting any result out of it. Here is the code what i have tried
'scala> class table(Input: Int) {
     |  def main(args: Array[String]) {
     |     var num = 0;
     |      for(i <-(1 to 10)) { num +=Input
     |      println(num)
     | }
     | }}
defined class table

scala> var x = new table(3)
x: table = table@7891742e'

Comment: Usually, we dont declare main method in class. For that we use singleton object. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Kandpal : Thanks for sharing the right way of doing.

Comment: Good way to say thanks is to upvote and accept the answer.